# Deezer IOS SDK issue with setPlayerProgress

Tags: ios, deezer

I have the Deezer Connect set up, logging in perfectly and remembering tokens etc, I can get track from a an album and play individual tracks/previews.

My problem appears when I use a scrubber to skip to a certain part of the track.

As far as I can tell this should be as simple as setting setPlayerProgress to the desired float number between 0.0 and 1.0. Alas everytime I scrub the track it stops playing and doesn't restart, while the player state is still **DeezerPlayerState_Playing**.

Comment: Did anyone manage to solve this issue? I'm also having the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the DeezerSample project?

On this project, you can find a DeezerAudioPlayer that manage the player (PlayerFactory *). This class implements the PlayerDelegate, check if your player manager implements it.

DeezerAudioPlayer also includes a method:

> - (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)progress

This class works fine for me. You can try to base your code on this class or compare to your own code to have some answers.

Hope it can help.